# Property and method with the same name

Tags: python-3.x, methods, properties

To simplify the problem, let's consider the following class

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.ndarray([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._array = np.ndarray([0, 1, 2, 3])
    
    @property
    def array(self):
        return self._array
```

so, what I can do is

```
cls = MyClass()
print(cls.array)  # [0 1 2 3]
```

Now, I would like to interpolate my arrays with a method which possibly has the same name of my property, so that my class would become something like

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.ndarray([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._array = np.ndarray([0, 1, 2, 3])
    
    @property
    def array(self):
        return self._array

    def array(self, vector):
        return np.interp(vector, self._time, self._array)
```

so that I can do both

```
cls = MyClass()
print(cls.array)  # [0 1 2 3]
print(cls.array([1.5, 2.5]))  # [1.5 2.5]
```

How can I do this? I tried with https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/ but I didn't succeed.

Also, consider that I am using a property because `self._array` cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

How about making vector optional:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.ndarray([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._array = np.ndarray([0, 1, 2, 3])

    def array(self, vector=None):
        if not vector:
            return self._array
        return np.interp(vector, self._time, self._array)
```